# Creating rasters from a list of matrices

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, raster

I would like to create three rasters out of the following list.

```
y <- matrix(1:300,100,3)
n <- c(1,2,3)
rep = 200

valuematrix <- vector("list",ncol(y))

for (i in 1:ncol(y)) {
        newmatrix <- replicate(rep,y[,i])
        valuematrix[[i]] <- newmatrix
}
```

Now that I have a list with 3 matrices each I want to create three rasters with names raster1, raster2, raster3 (I am not doing it right, though)

```
library(sp)
library(raster)    
for (i in 1:length(valuematrix)) {
            newraster <- raster(valuematrix[[i]])
            valum[[paste0("matrix", i)]] <- newraster
    }
```

Help how to change the last piece of code will be much appreciated.

Comment: You could keep it in a list `setNames(lapply(valuematrix, function(x) raster(x)), paste0('raster',1:3))` instead of having different objects in the global environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can keep create `raster` in a 'list', if needed, we can name the list elements with `setNames`

```
 lst <- setNames(lapply(valuematrix, raster), paste0('raster',1:3))
```

For `stack`ing and other operations, this can be used

```
 stack(lst)
```